# Javascript: dereference array of arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[
   [
      [
         {
            "text":"1"
         }
      ],
   ],
   [
      [
         {
            "text":"2"
         }
      ],
   ]
]
```

and I would like to remove the outer array so it looks like this:

```
[
   [
      {
         "text":"1"
      }
   ],
],
[
   [
      {
         "text":"2"
      }
   ],
]
```

I've tried using `arr[0]` to dereference but that loses the second element!

```
[
   [
      {
         "text":"1"
      }
   ]
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by dereference? The original object is an array with two items. Your attempt of `arr[0]` simply accesses the first item in the array. Perhaps you are wanting to remove a level of nesting from items in `arr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an array with two members, each of which contains an object member:

```
const arr = [
   [
      [
         {
            "text":"1"
         }
      ],
   ],
   [
      [
         {
            "text":"2"
         }
      ],
   ]
]
```

When you do `arr[0]`, you are getting the first of those arrays.

What I think you want to do is "flatten" the array.  You could either write your own flattening function, or use one from a library like Lodash.

But if you did want to write your own code, you could simply write:

```
const flatArr = [arr[0][0], arr[1][0]]
```

... but a `flatten` function from Lodash or elsewhere will handle many other cases of nested arrays.

**EDIT:**  As Sebastian Simon pointed out in the comments, another option is the new (and not yet in Edge or Internet Explorer) `flat` method.  If you use Babel or a polyfill or something to support those browsers, you can just do:

```
const flatArr = arr.flat(2);
```

Comment: Just [`arr.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility) is enough, if possible.

Comment: If you call `arr.flat()` on the `arr` variable I defined, it will just return the same nested arrays.  However an `arr.flat(2)` (to reach two layers deep, into the nested object inside the nested array) *will* work ... but it's not yet supported in Edge/IE, so you'll want some sort of polyfill or something if you use it.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Since the second level is just a single element array you can also get rid of the inner array instead of the outer using `map` -- `arr.map(x=>x[0])`